# cant access from filezilla when creating a user and folder from bash with different name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have been trying to run the following script in order to create a folder and then assign a username and password to this folder. Everything is working such as adding a new user and also creating the folder. but when I try to access from FileZilla it does not work and I am not able to connect it, the errors are above. but If I assign the username and foldername with the same "name" then it connects.

This is the bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash        
GROUP="ftp"
FOLDERNAME=$1
USERNAME=$2
PASSWORD=$3        
# Add new user
/usr/sbin/useradd -n $USERNAME -g $GROUP
# Create directory and subdirectory
/bin/mkdir -p /ftpchroot/$FOLDERNAME/upload    
cd /ftpchroot/$FOLDERNAME
# Change Owner/Group
chown $USERNAME:$GROUP upload/
# Setting tomcat ACL
/usr/bin/setfacl -Rm u:tomcat:rwx upload/ && setfacl -Rdm u:tomcat:rwx upload/

# Setting password
echo -e $USERNAME:$PASSWORD | chpasswd

/usr/sbin/edquota -p user01 $USERNAME

GOTERROR=$?
```

try:
`sh bash.sh folder1 user1 pass` => Error to connect with filezilla 
*Error:         Connection reset by peer

Error:          Could not connect to server*

`sh bash.sh user2 user2 pass` => connect with filezilla and access to the upload folder

any ideas?

Comment: Check your ftp program allows the new user

Comment: @KOrrosh-sh Can you add the version and name of your ftp server, and the output from its log file when the connection fails - thanks.

Comment: I will ask it from server assistant. but why do you need it? As I mentioned if I assign the username and name of folder with the same name like the example, it works.

Comment: "Connection reset by peer". Your 'peer' in this case is the ftp server. The server log is likely to contain a line saying why.  Alternatively, have you tried disabling the 'tomcat ACL' stuff to simplify the problem? ftp servers have a very large number of options, and there are many different variations. These problems are almost always solved by reading the correct log file / error message. Terms like 'linux' and 'ftp server' are too generic. Can't help you further, sorry.